# How to combine different sparse matrix in Python?

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, deep-learning, feature-extraction, feature-detection

I am building Machine Learning model using sci-kit learn. My dataset is number of svm files. I've loaded that files using sklearn. It returns data as a sparse matrix and target as a numpy array. Now the problem is, different files have different dimensions and hence it can't be joined together to form one large matrix.

For ex,

For one file - X is <16000x**3231949** sparse matrix of type ''
    with 1847536 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>

For other file (from same dataset) - X is  <20000x**3231955** sparse matrix of type ''
    with 2304202 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>

There are more than 100 files in this dataset. They have different number of features, what to do?

Thanks.

Comment: This can't be answered without more information. It also has not much to do with sparse data-structures. It's your task to know how there is a feature-difference and what exactly that means. We can't guess this. (Of course you could just trim the last 6 features from the second and can use scipy.sparse.vstack to merge these; but well... no one knows what we are throwing away)

Comment: Addition: the trimming-approach also assumes, that there were featured added at the end. If these were added at the beginning and we do this, most classifiers will fail because the order of features is broken then.

Comment: Thanks for your informative comment. To be specific, I am using this data http://sysnet.ucsd.edu/projects/url/ to classify whether given URL is malicious or not. This dataset contains 120 svmlight files. How can store features/target from each file to one matrix?   On trimming-approach, Wouldn't it lose some important features? And above-mentioned data are from two files only. There might be a larger difference in a number of features between multiple files.